# Angular doesnt destroy source component after routing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular8

I am building an angular 8 app which has 2 component: LandingComponent, BlogDetailComponent and of course main component AppComponent

As you can see below, There is routing from LandingComponent to BlogDetailComponent. When i click Blog Detail anchor, it succesfully redirects the page to BlogDetailComponent but problem is that directed page also contains landing page info. Like this;

```
Landing Page

Blog Detail Content
```

I am confused , i am expecting source page to be destroyed and target page to be created. But I guess I am wrong. Any help ?

app-component.html

```
<html>
<app-landing></app-landing>
</html>
```

landing-component.html

```
    ...
<li><a routerLink="blog-detail">Landing Page</a></li>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
   ...
```

blog-detail-component.html

```
    ...
   <div>Blog Detail Content</>
   ...
```

app-routing-module.ts

```
    ...
    const routes: Routes = [
        { path: 'blog-detail', component: BlogDetailComponent }
    ];

    @NgModule({
       declarations: [],
       imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
       exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Place **<router-outlet></router-outlet>** in app.component.html not in landing-component.html, and create a new route **{ path: '', component: LandingComponent }** to load landing component by default

Comment: it worked @Abhijit i also removed <app-landing></app-landing> from app-component.html so that all directions based on routes file. Thank you. if you add as answer. I will approve.

Comment: that's good you fixed it, added as answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in **app.component.html** not in **landing-component.html**, and create a new route `{ path: '', component: LandingComponent }`
to load landing component by default